# Get all conversations from one user in different chats MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am working on a facebook style chat and am trying to get all the latest conversations from one user with other users. 
Right now I am getting all the latest conversations but in the case that the other user has written to me. What I want to do is for example I have 2 conversations, conversation 1 is the latest I wrote into, but now I write into conversation 2, when I refresh the page conversation 2 will be first.
Now if the other person of conversation 1 writes me, if I refresh page conversation 1 will be first.
This are the 2 tables I am working with:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int(255) not null auto_increment,
    username varchar(150) null,
    email varchar(150) null,
    password varchar(255) null,
    salt varchar(255) null,
    pic varchar(255) not null,
    primary key(id)
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE chat (
    id int(255) not null auto_increment,
    id_us int(255) not null,
    id_receptor int(255) not null,
    message varchar(3000) not null,
    chat_date datetime not null,
    primary key (id),
    index chatUsId(id_us),
    index chatRecId(id_receptor),
    foreign key (id_us) references users(id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key (id_receptor) references users(id) on delete cascade
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this is the query I am using

```
SELECT m.id_us, m.id_receptor, u.username, u.pic 
FROM users AS u, chat AS m
WHERE (m.id_us = u.id  AND m.id_receptor =:id_us or m.id_receptor = u.id AND m.id_us =:id_us)
AND m.chat_date = (SELECT MAX( c.chat_date ) FROM chat AS c WHERE m.id_us = c.id_us AND m.id_receptor = c.id_receptor ) 
group by u.username
ORDER BY m.id DESC
```

In this case :id_us could be for example 1
I know its not correct as it is not doing what I would like it to do, but I've been struggling trying to find the way to get the results as I want, but I am stucked, any help will be apreciated.
To explain myself better, what I am trying to do is for example when you chat in facebook, the facebook messages list to view your latest conversations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK how about this: (using 123 for id of user1)

```
   select T1.user2_id, users.username, users.pic, max(cdate) maxDate from
   (select chat.id_receptor user2_id, max(chat_date) cdate
   from chat 
   where chat.id_us=123
   group by chat.id_receptor
   union distinct
   (select  chat.id_us user2_id, max(chat_date) cdate
   from chat  where chat.id_receptor = 123
   group by chat.id_us)) T1
   inner join users on (users.id = T1.user2_id)
   group by T1.user2_id
   order by maxDate desc
```

Comment: Yes, it did exactly what I needed, and also learned something new as I wouldn't have been able to prepare that query, it took me to investigate about using union as I hadn't worked with it. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Check below question

Answer (score 0):

I want recent message also like whatsapp, and I have update your query as per my tables.

```
select T1.user2_id, message, user_profile.user_name, user_profile.avatar, max(cdate) message_date from (select messages.receiver_id user2_id, messages.message, (message_date) cdate from messages where messages.sender_id=2 group by messages.receiver_id union distinct(select  messages.sender_id user2_id, messages.message, max(message_date) cdate from messages  where messages.receiver_id = 2 group by messages.sender_id)) T1 inner join user_profile on (user_profile.id = T1.user2_id) group by T1.user2_id order by message_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added another SELECT + JOIN. Please refer to below and let me know if any questions, will try to answer.

I would like to note that even though the above answer is marked is correct, in my understanding it does not covers the full needs of requested query as does not display the key item - i.e. last message per each chat.

```
$sql="
SELECT T2.maxDate, T2.user2_id, T2.ava, T2.userName,chat.user_to,chat.user_from,chat.body,chat.viewed FROM (SELECT T1.user2_id, users.userName, users.ava, max(cdate) maxDate FROM
            (SELECT chat.user_to user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate
                FROM chat WHERE chat.user_from=18
                GROUP BY chat.user_to
            union distinct
            (SELECT chat.user_from user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate
                FROM chat WHERE chat.user_to=18
                GROUP BY chat.user_from)) T1
            inner join users on (users.userID = T1.user2_id)
            group by T1.user2_id
            order by maxDate desc) T2
            join chat on (T2.maxDate = chat.msg_time) ORDER BY T2.maxDate DESC";
```