# Get all conversations from one user in different chats

Tags: mysql, sql

My question goes as continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537565/get-all-conversations-from-one-user-in-different-chats-mysql/47998947?noredirect=1#comment82966806_47998947) post.

In there, you may have noticed that the query marked as answered does not really outputs the message body itself.

For my case, what I need is output a WhatsApp-style 'Chats' view.

This query almost solves it:

```
SELECT T1.user2_id, users.userName, users.ava, max(cdate) maxDate FROM
            (SELECT user_to user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate
                FROM chat WHERE user_from=:id
                GROUP BY user_to
            union distinct
            (SELECT user_from user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate
                FROM chat WHERE user_to = :id
                GROUP BY user_from)) T1
            inner join users on (users.userID = T1.user2_id)
            group by T1.user2_id
            order by maxDate desc
```

But the remaining thing unsettled is: if I just add msg ('msg' holds the actual message and is a column in table 'chat') to each of SELECTs, the query  selects wrong messages. While I understand why this happens, I can't really get it working as it should. Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrapped it in another SELECT + JOIN.

What exactly query does: fetches all chats for given user, gets the latest message per each chat (be it the one sent by logged-in user, or received by logged-in user from another user (no doubling of result takes place)), sorts all chats by descending date, i.e. most recent on top.

```
$sql="
SELECT T2.maxDate, T2.user2_id, T2.ava, T2.userName,chat.user_to, chat.user_from,chat.body,chat.viewed FROM 
(SELECT T1.user2_id, users.userName, users.ava, max(cdate) maxDate FROM
                (SELECT chat.user_to user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate
                    FROM chat WHERE chat.user_from=18
                    GROUP BY chat.user_to
                union distinct
                (SELECT chat.user_from user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate
                    FROM chat WHERE chat.user_to=18
                    GROUP BY chat.user_from)) T1
                inner join users on (users.userID = T1.user2_id)
                group by T1.user2_id
                order by maxDate desc) T2
                join chat on (T2.maxDate = chat.msg_time) ORDER BY T2.maxDate DESC";
```